# What benefit do I get for 100% synchronization?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

I see that many missions have a challenge associated with them, in order to get 100% synchronization.  What benefit(s) do I get for achieving 100% synchronization?  Some of the challenges are kind of hard, and there seem to be a million of them, so I want to understand if it is worth it.

Comment: I think you get a trophy/achievement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of achievements associated with synchronization:

- Perfect Recall - for achieving 100% sync in an entire sequence
- Il Principe - for achieving 100% sync in the entire game, plus the Da Vinci Disappearance DLC (requires the aforementioned DLC)

Each sequence also has [an associated cheat](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Assassin%27s_Creed:_Brotherhood_cheats) that is unlocked for 100% sync, which can be used in single player.  You can only use cheats while replaying a mission, so they're really more for replay value than for making your life easier.

There are also a series of "repressed memories" that you unlock as you increase your "overall" synchronization, and completing missions with 100% sync is a good way to increase this total.  However, the last one of these is unlocked at 75% total synchronization, so 100%'ing the entire game isn't required.  These memories are from before Ezio became an assassin, and center around his relationship with [Cristina Vespucci](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Cristina_Vespucci).